# how to remove the 'PATH' in ResponseStatusException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I like to know how to remove this path parameter in the error json, which is thrown from my Spring Boot Rest service.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-11-02T09:27:33.993+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": " Employee Not Found :1265",
    "path": "/1265"
}
```

Comment: Create a custom POJO which extends this class and just omit the `path` variable in your POJO. deserialize the response into your custom POJO

Answer (score 0):

As you are using spring, I would highly recommend to create a global exception handler by implementing `@ControllerAdvice` in your project. This would help you to write custom exception classes that would help your project in many ways

1. It gives us full control over the body of the response as well as the status code.
2. It provides mapping of several exceptions to the same method, to be
   handled together.
3. It makes good use of the newer RESTful ResposeEntity response

Here are some links to get you started.

https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-controlleradvice-exceptionhandler/

https://zetcode.com/springboot/controlleradvice/